# My first e-mail writing. Could you look over this, please?

Tags: email

Hello thanks for coming here. Could you look over this e-mail writing to correct grammatic errors and awkward expressions? This is my first time to write an e-mail of introducing my items to buyers in English. I sincerely appreciate your recommendations for a better letter.
Thanks again!

Dear Sir or Madam,

Hi, my name is X from A in Korea.

I received your address from the B fair and would like to introduce Italian foods beloved around the world.
First of all, I’d like to introduce our company, A.

A has an excellent reputation with 40 years history of making Italian Home Meal Replacement(HMR) and it has already numerous clients by exporting to over 50 countries. We have International certificates such as X,Y, and Z, which guarantees its food safety and highly skilled manufacturing ability.

Our main product is M, which is Italian pasta and the brand name is called P.
P has some merits in its character.
△ Various flavors: ~~
△ Two types of packaging: cup type and pouch type.
△ Long enough shelf life : 1 year at room temperature
△ Easy to cook: ~~

Besides, we manufacture other items such as C, D, and E. These are also beloved Italian foods around the world.

Enclosed with this letter is a catalog of A and a price list of items above.
And you can see more details in following reference.
△ www.~~
△ www.~~

Please let me know, if you are interested in our items.
I am looking forward to speaking with you and hope this is the beginning of our page.

Sincerely,

Comment: Hi, Annie. Unfortunately, it is the official policy of this forum not to offer a proof-reading service. We can only answer questions about individual problems. I don't see any serious errors in your text.

Comment: Oh, thank you for informing that. I didn't know about the detailed policy. I also appreciate for your comment that  there's no serious errors!

Comment: I suggest you replace the word "beloved" - it sounds awkward to me.